# Rails field_for confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Note that I am pretty new to rails, so please don't hate me too much.

I want to have 2 different table rows of entries for an object. From what I understand, the code would look like this.

```
<%= form_for(@object) do |f| %>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th> Col 1 </th>
    <th> Col 2 </th>
    <th> Col 3 </th>
    <th> Col 4 </th>
    <th> Col 5 </th>
    <th> Col 6 </th>
    <th> Col 7 </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!-- entries 1-7 here --!>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!-- entries 8-14 here --!>
  </tr>
</table>
<% end %>
```

But from what I can tell, using something like `<% fields_for(@object.entries) do |entry| %>` forces me to go through all of them at once whe I really just want to do the first half than the second half. I know that I will always have 14 entries per object (1 a day for 2 weeks), and I'd like to see them in 2 rows (1 row per week).  Any ideas how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`#each_slice`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/Enumerable#each_slice-instance_method) from Enumerable to chunk them as you iterate.  Something like:

```
<%= form_for(@object) do |f| %>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th> Col 1 </th>
    <th> Col 2 </th>
    <th> Col 3 </th>
    <th> Col 4 </th>
    <th> Col 5 </th>
    <th> Col 6 </th>
    <th> Col 7 </th>
  </tr>
  <% @object.entries.each_slice(7) do |arr| %>
    <% arr.each do |obj| %>
      <tr>
        <!-- entries n-n+7 here -->
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</table>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

fields_for accepts array so you should be able to just pass entries you need:

```
<% fields_for(@object.entries[0,7]) do |entry| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

or even combine it with each_slice (or in_groups_of) from the answer above:

```
<% @object.entries.each_slice(7) do |entries| %>
  <% fields_for(entries) do |entry| %>
    ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```